# OneVsRestClassifier failed to predict binarize multi-class label

Tags: python, classification, random-forest, cross-validation

i've perform OneVsRestClassifier with randorm fores classifier to binarize class label. i used Kfold cross validation. i performed binarize class for plotting roc curve

my problem is classifier.predict method failed to predict in some record.
here's my code

```
# Define classifier
classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=False, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=13, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=4, min_samples_split=10,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=100, n_jobs=3,
            oob_score=False, random_state=27, verbose=0, warm_start=False))

# Define Method
kf = KFold(n_splits=3, random_state=27, shuffle=True)

scores = []
y_preds = []
y_trues = []
y_probs = []
for train_indices, test_indices in kf.split(X):
    # Perform Fold Validation
    classifier.fit(X[train_indices], y[train_indices])
    y_pred = classifier.predict(X[test_indices])
    y_true = y[test_indices]
    score = classifier.score(X[test_indices], y_true)
    y_prob = classifier.predict_proba(X[test_indices])

    # Append to list
    scores.append(score)
    y_preds.append(y_pred)
    y_trues.append(y_true)
    y_probs.append(y_prob)

    print('iteration..')

scores = np.array(scores)
ypred = np.concatenate(np.array(y_preds))
ytrue = np.concatenate(np.array(y_trues))
yprob = np.concatenate(np.array(y_probs))
```

my ytrue, ypred, and yprob result

```
ytrue 
 [[0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1]
 ...
 [1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0]]
ypred 
 [[0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1]
 ...
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]]
yprob 
 [[0.0284438 0.        0.0237302 0.4376503 0.070079  0.3654891]
 [0.018646  0.        0.0111984 0.5008399 0.1122584 0.3558225]
 [0.0770742 0.        0.1195185 0.0839903 0.1776736 0.6168349]
 ...
 [0.0319885 0.0194651 0.2914288 0.1826586 0.3700613 0.1913803]
 [0.0037897 0.0053333 0.0129757 0.552535  0.2664548 0.1772928]
 [0.0030278 0.0026374 0.0673323 0.4866199 0.2321866 0.260554 ]]
```

why some record/row does not has predicted class? what's wrong with my code?

Comment: You can try `predict_proba` instead of `predict` and see if your classifier is predicting all in one or two classes, or if the predicted probabilities are close but one is slightly more than the others

Comment: i've done predict_proba and save it to yscore list. nothing wrong with my predict_proba. i need the predict value to make confussion matrix

Comment: And what are the probability values in the rows where you have no predicted positive classes?

Comment: i edited the question to show the predict_proba result in yprob array. it has value but not predict any class

Comment: One interesting thing I see is that none of the rows with no prediction has any probability above 50%. Can you confirm in the full dataset if that holds true, or if that's just a coincidence based on the 6 rows provided?

Comment: you right, just realize that interesting thing. i preformed ypred.sum(axis=1) to check which one has predicted class value and not. only 52 out of 185 row that gave predicted class

Comment: So if none of your OvR classfiers got more than 50% of the vote, than it doesn't win as the predicted class, perhaps? I'm not familiar enough with the OneVsRest to say for certain, but that makes sense to me